# Should I use database for only two string? (Android-java)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have two edittext and save button. When application is started, last data will coming. I know SQL ite database for it but can I use a text file or another thing. Is Sqlite correct always? And can I give example for save data from two edittext , and I get data to edittext.

Comment: I think SharedPreferences would be better for only two values.

Answer (score 3):

[Developers Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) says:

> "If you have a relatively small collection of key-values that you'd like to save, you should use the [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) APIs"